# URL Domino move to Linux case sensitive?

Tags: linux, xpages, lotus-domino

I did the migration of IBM Domino R9.0.1FP1 server from Windows 2003 to Linux Centos 6.6

All work correct, but sometime (this is the strange) some URL is not open and go into 404 error.
So I have debug this problem...and I see for example if you have a URL:

```
http://www.mysite.it/testfolder/viewpeople?openView [CORRECT in the filesystem]
```

if into the Browser you write:

```
http://www.mysite.it/TestFolder/viewpeople?openView [NOT CORRECT in the filesystem the Uppercase TestFolder]
```

the first time IBM Domino return a 404 error (page not found, but in Windows that is case insensitive work always...)

So after if I correct the URL in my Browser (replace the string with lowercase) work.

The magic is that from now...**Domino open both the URL???**

This is Mysterius?

someone has an explanation for me ?

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that Domino caches some of the information about the database. So once it has found it (with correct case) it will find it with whatever case you use in the url.

I am not aware of the exact implementation of this caching mechanism. And then if you restart (I think just the http server) then it hasn't got it in the cache - and will fail if you use wrong case...

I have decided to use all lowercase for filenames and directories for the same reason ;-) ... and I run a lot of applications on Linux. And if you calculate URLs in the system then just don't change the case (e.g. reuse what came from the existing url) and then you should be fine.

And the thing is that case sensitive URLs have been the nature of many systems (e.g. using servlets) - and now that we do XPages these are also case sensitive. So we should all think about it from the start when we design our web applications :-)

/John

Answer (score 1):

File names and folder names are case sensitive in Linux whereas not in Windows.

Quotation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity):

> In Unix filesystems, filenames are usually case-sensitive. Old Windows
>   filesystems (VFAT, FAT32) are not case-sensitive (there cannot be a
>   readme.txt and a Readme.txt in the same directory) but are
>   case-preserving, i.e. remembering the case of the letters. The
>   original FAT12 filesystem was case-insensitive.[7] Current Windows
>   file systems, like NTFS, are case-sensitive; that is a readme.txt and
>   a Readme.txt can exist in the same directory. However, the API for
>   file access in Windows applications is case-insensitive, which makes
>   the file names case-insensitive from a user point of view.[8]

Comment: Yes I know the difference from Windows and Linux...I don't know why after the URL is correct, this bypass the case sensitive  (you can digit case insensitive URL and the URL work well)

Comment: It has to be a special functionality of server that remembers successful URL reads with different casing. Normally it wouldn't correct the URL as it happens with e.g. Wikipedia URL. This functionality doesn't really help though as you have to insert the correct URL first.

Comment: Note that in Windows 7 it won't accept readme.txt and Readme.txt in the same folder. I'm not sure if the wikipedia quote is out of date or wrong. The same prevention occurs for folder names.

Comment: @Paul, probably the old revision http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Case_sensitivity&oldid=499257231  was better: "... you can have a readme.txt and a Readme.txt in the same folder, however, Windows disallows you to create a second file differing only in case"